# Increase in lens power

Tags: eye, eye-strain

I was allotted spectacles when I was in class 1.My lens power was then $-1$.Now after 12years it has became three times.I don't get why my lens power is increasing at such a fast rate.One reason I feel is use of computers and smartphones.I try to avoid them but it is a important part of my study.I fear if this continues I will be blind one day.Can anyone please suggest some measures I could take to avoid this.Please note I donot want to undertake a operation and wear contact lenses.Thanks.

Comment: From -1 to -3 in 12 years? That's not bad, I went from 0 to -2,5 in 4 years. As always, this very much depends on yourself and no one on the internet can examine you properly. **Talk to a doctor** and ask him exactly that. Having your question in written form will help you not omitting anything you wanted to ask.